# Fatal error while extending a class which does not have namespace

Tags: php, namespaces

I have two classes, `Database` and `States`. The class `Database` has no namespace assigned. The class `States`, written in file states.php, has a namespace assigned as below:

```
namespace Resources;      
require_once 'database.php';
  
$states = new States();
echo $states->readAll();

class States extends Database{
    private $db;
  
    public function __construct(){
      $this->db = new Database();
    }
  
    function readAll(){
      return $this->db->Execute('SELECT * FROM states;');
    }      
}
```

If I enter the url *http://localhost/mydomain/objects/states.php* which should instantiate the class and show list of states, an error is thrown as:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Resources\Database' not found in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\mydomain\objects\states.php on line 5

If I remove the line `namespace Resources;` the code runs.

I have recently decided to implemen namespaces in my website, so most likely, I am doing something wrong.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP manual has [a section introducing namespaces](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) which is well worth reading. In particular, have a look at [this page drawing the analogy to a file system](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php):

> The same principle can be applied to namespaced elements in PHP. For
> example, a class name can be referred to in three ways:
>
> 1. Unqualified name, or an unprefixed class name like `$a = new foo();` or `foo::staticmethod();`. If the current namespace is `currentnamespace`,
>    this resolves to `currentnamespace\foo`. If the code is global,
>    non-namespaced code, this resolves to `foo`.
> 2. Qualified name, or a prefixed class name like `$a = new subnamespace\foo();` or `subnamespace\foo::staticmethod();`. If the
>    current namespace is `currentnamespace`, this resolves to
>    `currentnamespace\subnamespace\foo`. If the code is global,
>    non-namespaced code, this resolves to `subnamespace\foo`.
> 3. Fully qualified name, or a prefixed name with global prefix operator like `$a = new \currentnamespace\foo();` or
>    `\currentnamespace\foo::staticmethod();`. This always resolves to the
>    literal name specified in the code, `currentnamespace\foo`.

In your example, `Database` is an "unqualified name", so point 1 applies. The current namespace is `Resources`, so it refers to `Resources\Database`. If you remove the `namespace Resources;` line, the code becomes "global, non-namespaced code", so it refers to just `Database`.

To refer to the class `Database` when the current namespace is `Resources`, you can use a "fully qualified name", as described in point 3. So in this case, you would write `class States extends \Database`.

There are other ways to write it, such as [adding `use` statements to import/alias a name](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php), but there's no point me copying the whole PHP manual here.

Comment: Thanks. Only adding a \ before `Database` did the job.